# Get unique items from list of lists?

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
animal_groups = [['fox','monkey', 'zebra'], ['snake','elephant', 'donkey'],['beetle', 'mole', 'mouse'],['fox','monkey', 'zebra']]
```

What is the best to remove duplicate lists? Using the above example, I am looking for code that would produce this:

```
uniq_animal_groups = [['fox','monkey', 'zebra'], ['snake','elephant', 'donkey'],['beetle', 'mole', 'mouse']]
```

I first thought I could use `set()`, but this doesn't appear to work on a list of lists. I also saw an example using `itertools`, but the code was not entirely clear to me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
uniq_animal_groups = set(map(tuple, animal_groups))
```

will do the trick, though you will end up with a set of tuples instead of a set of lists.  (Of course you could convert this back to a list of lists, but unless there is a specific reason to do so, why bother?)

Comment: incase you want to access the list of lists (eg. inspect `uniq_animal_groups[0]`, do  `uniq_animal_groups = list(set(map(tuple, animal_groups)))` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Convert the lists to tuples, and then you can put them into a set.

Essentially:

```
uniq_animal_groups = set(map(tuple, animal_groups))
```

If you prefer the result to be a list of lists, try:

```
uniq_animal_groups = [list(t) for t in set(map(tuple, animal_groups))]
```

or:

```
uniq_animal_groups = map(list, set(map(tuple, animal_groups)))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't care about the sorting of internal lists, convert everything to sets first:

```
uniq_animal_groups  = map(list, set(map(tuple, map(set, animal_groups))))
```