# How to get unique values from a python list of objects

Tags: python, list

I have a class:

```
class Car:
    make
    model
    year
```

I have a list of Cars and want to get a list of unique models among my Cars.

The list is potentially tens of thousands of items. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean models that are only in the list once or to shorten the list to only have one of each?

Comment: build a set, i suppose?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926928/get-unique-items-from-list-of-lists   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479897/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-if-the-item-order-is-not-impo

Comment: I am not sure this is a duplicate, the OP may want to find models that only appear once which the dup will not solve

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use a [`set` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Sets are unordered collections of unique elements, meaning that any duplicates will be removed.

```
cars = [...] # A list of Car objects.

models = {car.model for car in cars}
```

This will iterate over your list `cars` and add the each `car.model` value at most once, meaning it will be a unique collection.

Comment: Many people find the curlies to read - they look like dictionaries. In that context, so as an alternative `models = list(set([car.model for car in cars]))`

Comment: you pay quite some price for getting rid of the curlies, don't you?

Comment: Yeah I think it's because first you create the full list (with duplicates) then you add it to a set (meaning you remove the duplicates) then you put it back in a list.

Comment: Feed your clock cycles to the god of the anti-curlie...

Answer (score 3):

Add a method to the class that returns a unique list

```
def unique(list1):
    # intilize a null list
    unique_list = []

    # traverse for all elements
    for x in list1:
        # check if exists in unique_list or not
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)

    return unique_list
```

Otherwise,

If you're looking to pass a dictionary of make, model year then you can use pandas dataframe in order to get the unique values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find cars that only appear once:

```
from collections import Counter
car_list = ["ford","toyota","toyota","honda"]
c = Counter(car_list)
cars = [model for model in c if c[model] == 1 ]
print cars
['honda', 'ford']
```

Comment: Yeah I read it differently (as the OP wanting the unique set of models that he had). Hopefully they'll reply and clear it up though :)

Comment: +1: either this is the answer the OP is looking for, or this is just a duplicate of 50 other questions.

Answer (score -4):

Now it depends on what you mean by unique. If you mean Exactly the same object then this should work:

```
def check_all_objects_unique(objects: List[Any]) -> bool:
unique_objects = set(objects)
if len(unique_objects) == len(objects):
    return True
elif len(unique_objects) < len(objects):
    return False
```

If by unique you mean objects with the same attribute values then other answers on here will help you.

Comment: You don't answer OPs question. This just checks if all elements are unique and in a very bad way at that. simply `return len(unique_objects) == len(objects)`